# Stroke Around View From Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I have a dark background in my application. When the keyboard comes on screen it creates a stroke around the view that contains the UITextField or UITextView. Is this a bug? Does anyone know of a workaround?

In the picture attached you'll see a white stroke going around the view under the top bar.

[image: Picture with Stroke]

Comment: I see a line under the top bar separating it from the rest of the screen. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yeah it actually goes around the whole view and it flickers. It's not supposed to be there. It only shows when the keyboard comes on screen.